# How to backup mysql using mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I am new to using mysql and i am trying to backup a mysql database using `mysqldump`.

So this is what i have done so far:-

1. I ssh'ed into my VM and run `mysql` to get into the `mysql CLI`
2. Then i ran the command `mysql> SHOW DATABASES;` which gives me the following output :-

   information|
   | rap_songs|
   | celebrities|
3. Now i am trying to backup my `rap songs` database and i run the following command :-

`mysql> mysqldump -u root -p rap_songs > rap_songs_backup.sql`

But nothing happens after this step. What am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What's in the `rap_songs_backup.sql` file?

Comment: Maybe you're outputting the file to the root folder for mysql. try `mysqldump -u root -p rap_songs > ./rap_songs_backup.sql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run **mysqldump** in `SSH terminal` not in `mysql terminal`

**For all database::**

```
mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction -u root -p > /all_databases.sql
```

**For one database (`rap_song` in this case)::**

```
mysqldump -u root -p rap_songs > /your_backup.sql
```

Now you need to go to `/` to see your files, **mysqldump** usually show nothing once its done terminal again avail for new cmd. So if terminal is again avail it means its done!

> **Non-root user | Permission denied error!**

Don't use `/your_backup.sql`

use `~/your_backup.sql` instead

**`~/` is your user data directory**

> **Mysqldump without password**

You can create a `.my.cnf` in `~/`

```
[mysqldump]
user=mysqluser
password=userpass
```

Then `chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf`

**now in your script or crontab don't mention `-p` or `--password` and when your cron or script execute it will automatically pick password from here**

Comment: I am getting the folliowng : 

`bash: /rap_songs_backup.sql: Permission denied`

Comment: I'm not recommend to store in root folder `/`, it's can be not permitted to current user. Prefer to store to current user home folder `~/backup.sql`

Comment: Is there a way to run the command without using a password?

Comment: @Somethingwhatever yes but highly insecure, update answer again i just updated

Comment: `mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`
I am getting this now

Comment: what `cmd` you are executing ?

Comment: `mysqldump -u root  rap_songs > ~/rap_songs_backup.sql`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223779/discussion-between-idlejatt-and-somethingwhatever).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had to run this query in order to circumvent the errors :-

```
mysqldump --complete-insert --routines --triggers --single-transaction
    rap_songs> rap_songs_backup.sql
```